# Need to put more information in NetworkX graph

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz, orgchart

I'm trying to build an organizational chart, but I need to enter more than one piece of information in the chart and insert people's photos. I will put it below as I did and I would like to know how I can put their photo and title under the names of people. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import sqlite3, pandas as pd, networkx as nx

con = sqlite3.connect('people.db')

qry="""
SELECT a1.id, a1.name as a1, a2.name as a2, a1.position as a3
FROM people a1
INNER JOIN people a2 ON a1.manager_id = a2.id
"""

emps=pd.read_sql(qry, con)

emps.rename(
columns={'a2' :'manager', 'a1' :'person', 'a3':'position'},
inplace=True
)

edgelist=emps[['person', 'manager',]]

print(edgelist)

orgchart=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edgelist, source='manager', target='person')

p=nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(orgchart)
p.write_png('orgchart.png')
```

In each circle I would like to put the name and below the position and photo. And if possible I would like to change the layout from circle to square.

Thank You!

Tried to read de docs, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> Tried to read de docs, but nothing

Just add [attributes](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#adding-attributes-to-graphs-nodes-and-edges) to the nodes, and they will be passed "as is" to graphviz.

E.g., if you have a node "Goerge", you can do:

```
orgchart.nodes['George']['color'] = 'red'
orgchart.nodes['George']['shape'] = 'box'
orgchart.nodes['George']['label'] = 'Georgie boy is a swell guy'
```

See the Graphviz documentation for [node (and edge) attributes](https://graphviz.org/documentation/).

As for adding images, there's the `image` attribute (use an absolute path to the image, because pydot switches the working directory to a temporary one), but it's shown as the node background, so use [HTML labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795411/annotate-dot-graphs-with-images) instead:

```
orgchart.nodes['George']['label'] = '<<TABLE><TR><TD>\\N</TD></TR><TR><TD><IMG SRC="/absolute/path/to/george.png"/></TD></TR></TABLE>>'
```

Comment: But I dont know the node names, it comes from database, how to do it?

Comment: The names of the nodes are the names of the people. It comes from the database (the `name` column).